# Snake problems - Movement

Tags: python, pygame

I am having some issues with my code in python, I am making a version of snake, my issue concerns the movement of the snake itself. I have gotten the directions working fine, I just need to make it so that the snake continues moving in the direction it has been told to do so via the key press, I also need to make it so that it is the one block, currently it shows all previous blocks once it has been moved.

```
import pygame, sys, time, random
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

size = width,height = 480, 480 #16x30,16x30
grey = (128,128,128)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
icon = pygame.image.load('snakeIcon.png')
newDir = 0
prevDir = 0
FPS = 8

xCoord = 10.0
yCoord = 10.0

#Main Program:
pygame.display.set_caption('Anthony\'s Snake')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
screen.fill(grey)

fpsTime = pygame.time.Clock()

gameB = pygame.image.load('gameB.png')
border = {}
createLvl()

snakeH = pygame.image.load('snakeH.png')
snake = {}

refreshScreen()

keyCheck = {'LEFT':bool(0), 'RIGHT':bool(0), 'UP':bool(0), 'DOWN':bool(0),    'ESC':bool(0)}

pygame.mixer.music.load('retroMusik.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.5)
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

while bool(1):
for i in range(1):
    snake[str(len(snake))]=snakeH.get_rect()
x = xCoord
y = yCoord
for i in range(len(snake)):
    snake[str(i)].x = x*16
    snake[str(i)].y = y*16

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type==QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == K_UP :
            keyCheck['UP'] = bool(1)
        if event.key == K_DOWN :
            keyCheck['DOWN'] = bool(1)
        if event.key == K_LEFT :
            keyCheck['LEFT'] = bool(1)
        if event.key == K_RIGHT :
            keyCheck['RIGHT'] = bool(1)
        if event.key == K_ESCAPE :
            keyCheck['ESC'] = bool(1)

    if event.type == KEYUP:
        if event.key == K_UP :
            keyCheck['UP'] = bool(0)
        elif event.key == K_DOWN :
            keyCheck['DOWN'] = bool(0)
        elif event.key == K_LEFT :
            keyCheck['LEFT'] = bool(0)
        elif event.key == K_RIGHT :
            keyCheck['RIGHT'] = bool(0)
        elif event.key == K_ESCAPE :
            keyCheck['ESC'] = bool(0)

if keyCheck['UP']:
    if prevDir != 'DOWN':
        newDir = 'UP'
        print('Direction changed to UP')
if keyCheck['DOWN']:
    if prevDir != 'UP':
        newDir = 'DOWN'
        print('Direction changed to DOWN')
if keyCheck['LEFT']:
    if prevDir != 'RIGHT':
        newDir = 'LEFT'
        print('Direction changed to LEFT')
if keyCheck['RIGHT']:
    if prevDir != 'LEFT':
        newDir = 'RIGHT'
        print('Direction changed to RIGHT')
prevDir = newDir


if keyCheck['UP'] == bool(1):
    yCoord -= 1
if keyCheck['DOWN'] == bool(1):
    yCoord += 1
if keyCheck['LEFT'] == bool(1):
    xCoord -= 1
if keyCheck['RIGHT'] == bool(1):
    xCoord += 1

refreshScreen()
fpsTime.tick(FPS)
```

Please be soft on me, I am still new to this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please fix your indentations first, helps us a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

I think your animation doesn't work right because you don't erase (cover with background) the screen before drawing. See [this](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/MoveIt.html) Pygame tutorial for slow and detailed explanation.

Don't use `bool(1)`. Use `True` and `False`.

I'm not sure but I think the problem with the snake not moving is either A) you reset your control/movement variable or B) you don't check it every "round"/frame.

I'd really recommend finding some tutorial (or something) and read some Python code by other people, your code could use a lot of improvement (this isn't *bad*, the important thing is trying to improve).

Comment: Thank you, any help is greatly appreciated. I will look into it. Cheers! :-)